# Azure Web App Disk Queue for no reason

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a small web API with a single controller hosted as WebApp(scaled out), but when under load I see that there is a disk queue
[image]

Data returned from the controller is from MemoryCache, nothing to require disk usage.
If I connect through FTP, there is nothing new created in `LogFiles` or any other folder. So where is this Disk Queue coming from?
Could it affect the performance? (There is a HTTP queue for no apparent reason, there are multiple instances and CPU is at 50%, memory not even 20%)

Comment: Where does the data you have in MemoryCache come from? And what's the cache's memory footprint? Could it be you're doing disk I/O to get this data? There's probably a reason for the Disk Queue, you're just not sure what it is yet ;)

Comment: @RickvandenBosch - From a Sql Database, for testing I use a single route, the data is always cached. The other thing I have added is Application Insights SDK, nothing else.

Comment: If there's only one controller, maybe you can share some (relevant) code?

Comment: @RickvandenBosch Nothing to show, it's just a line `return _dataProvider.GetDogs();` where it gets record from DB or MemoryCache. Running it locally I can see that IIS is writing on disk 4MB/s, but I am not sure what, and don't think this would cause disk queues.

Answer (score 0):

> So where is this Disk Queue coming from?

Based on my understanding, when we use `MemoryCache` it doesn't indicate that it  has no disk I/O. While process a program, but it doesn't indicate that all of the data is stored in the physically  memory, some of it will be stored in the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). It should be paging file,(pagefile.sys). It needs to read data from disk. In the local environment we could use microsfot supplied [RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) tool to know how Windows is assigning physical memory, how much file data is cached in RAM, or how much RAM is used by the kernel and device drivers.

Comment: Why would it use virtual memory when RAM usage is at 10%?

Comment: In my option, it doesn't mean that if RAM are all used then to use the virtual memory, we  could get more info about [Why do we need virtual memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349572/why-do-we-need-virtual-memory).